# Round Double value in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-category, objective-c-2.0

How to round double value in objective c if the value is 1.66 it show value to 1.55 there is missing a point value which makes a difference if the calculations are higher ?

```
self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",totalPrice];
```

i have used multiple others things including formatter but this issue remain same

calculations from calculator show value like 293.76 but from this way it show value 293.75 i need the value to be 293.76

Comment: ??? that ".2f" should in most cases round correctly - do you perhaps mean you also want to round the value itself and use that rather than the multiprecision one in subsequent calculations?

Comment: @skaak i just want to round the value in some cases value is correct but when it comes to .75 this make an issue of missing .1 value in it how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible, complete example, where you declare a double variable, assign a value, perform the rounding, and show us what's wrong?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen 
`totalPrice= totalPrice+([cart.quantity doubleValue]*[cart.price_vat doubleValue]);`
i have used this and assigning  this to my label but when price is 293.76 it show 293.75
`self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",totalPrice];`

Comment: @iOSAppTester - I think you need to double-check your math. This example - https://pastebin.com/3tVmwde9 - works fine. It generates a `double` of `293.76` (actual value is really `293.75999999999999` because floating point), and the string generated by `NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", totalPrice];` is as expected... **"293.76"**

Comment: @DonMag your given link is not working

Comment: @iOSAppTester - not sure what you mean... the **link** doesn't take you to the code? Or you run the code and you're getting different results?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to illustrate.

All looks good!? What is the problem?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString * round02( double val )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", val];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        double x = 0;

        while ( x < 3 )
        {
            x += 0.001;
            NSLog ( @"Have %f becomes %@ and %@", x, round02( x ), round02( -x ) );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***time passes***

In fact, I can see lots of trouble. Not sure if this is what is bugging you, but e.g. in the output it shows

```
2021-03-04 12:37:13.116147+0200 Rounding[15709:202740] Have 2.723000 becomes 2.72 and -2.72
2021-03-04 12:37:13.116210+0200 Rounding[15709:202740] Have 2.724000 becomes 2.72 and -2.72
2021-03-04 12:37:13.116316+0200 Rounding[15709:202740] Have 2.725000 becomes 2.72 and -2.72
2021-03-04 12:37:13.116383+0200 Rounding[15709:202740] Have 2.726000 becomes 2.73 and -2.73
```

The last `2.72` should have been a `2.73` but, again this is a complex issue. Here is a simple way to solve it - add a tolerance as in the example below.

```
NSString * round02( double val )
{
    double tol = 0.0005;

    if ( val >= 0 )
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", val + tol];
    }
    else
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", val - tol];
    }
}
```

This does not directly address the complexities and there are cases where this will fail as well, but it will go a long way to getting the job done, e.g. now the output reads

```
2021-03-04 12:40:11.274826+0200 Rounding[15727:204617] Have 2.723000 becomes 2.72 and -2.72
2021-03-04 12:40:11.274941+0200 Rounding[15727:204617] Have 2.724000 becomes 2.72 and -2.72
2021-03-04 12:40:11.275016+0200 Rounding[15727:204617] Have 2.725000 becomes 2.73 and -2.73
2021-03-04 12:40:11.275096+0200 Rounding[15727:204617] Have 2.726000 becomes 2.73 and -2.73
```